# How do I know if the two cells are merged?

Tags: c#, excel, merge, cell, npoi

I am using NPOI for some excel manipulation.

I am trying to copy three cells A1,B1,C1 to down the row. Cells A1 and B1 are merged.

When i tried it, it is moved to A2,B2,C2 but A2 and B2 not merged.

Actually before copying the cells, How could i find whether the cell is stand alone or it is merged with some others?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this might help you, but if you can retrieve a cell object, you could use the ".MergeCells" property.

```
Range("A1").MergeCells
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a cell is merged using

```
if (cell.IsMergedCell)
```

on the actual NPOI UserMode.ICell object.